# what is error in following code

Tags: php, html

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM libsutdent where libid='$_POST[libid]'");
           $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
           if($rowcount==1)
          {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
             $libid=$row['libid'];
             $regno= $row['regno'] ;
             $name= $row['stuname'] ;
             $branch= $row['branch'] ;
             $semester= $row['semester'] ;
             $section= $row['section'] ;
             $yearofadm= $row['yearofadm'];
             }
          }
```

Comment: I feel it should be `libstudent` instead of `libsutdent` [The table name]

Comment: It's probably the typo in your SQL, but presumably you have run this code and have an error message that would be useful to include in your post.

Comment: You're injecting variables into your query instead of using prepared statements and bind variables. That said, StackOverflow requires you to do an effort yourself, and you've clearly done nothing but copy paste your code here.

Comment: Seems to be infinite loop! If thats what you are asking. Remove the while and just assign $row=mysqli_fecth_array($result).

Note: i am not php expert - by looking at code, it doesn't seem right.

Also, you can better what is the error? and What you are expecting it to be... Needs more explanation.

Thanks, Rizwan

Comment: @RizwanAhmed The way that `mysqli_fetch_array` works is that it returns a new row every time it's called until it's out of rows where it'll return `false` (and `$row` won't be truthy, and the loop would stop).

Answer (score 3):

Dont post anything directly in database as its a threat to data security (SQL Injection)

```
$libid = $_POST['libid'];
$libid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $libid);
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM libsutdent where libid='".$libid."'");
```

Comment: replace $dbc with your database connection ... sorry forgot to say this

Comment: My bad, wasnt thinking about that ....sorry

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your mysql field is really libsutdent.  Seems like it should be libstudent.

Then Place {} around your Post variable. ie {$_POST[\"libid\"]}.

Conversely you can place another step in your code like:
$libid = $_POST["libid"];

I think you can do without the quotes around libid, but I always think it reads better to add them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM libsutdent where libid='$_POST[libid]'");
```

Should be

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM libsutdent where libid='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['libid'])."'");
```

Comment: The code still contains a massive gaping SQL injection security flaw.

Comment: But that does not mean it has errors

Comment: Except if - you know - `$_POST['libid']` has any `'` character in it. Do you know if it does? Do you think it's a good idea to post bad practice code for someone who obviously can't do debugging himself?

Comment: You probably should post the right answer, rather than voting down others who try to help

Comment: Now you use `mysql_real_escape_string`. Not only has it been deprecated for years but it also doesn't work with `mysqli_`. This is "helpful" in the same way that your friend says that he can't get inside his house because he forgot the key, and your solution is  to break the window. It works - but he's left with a gaping hole in his house.